# Conversion from type "DBNull" to type 'string' is not valid error

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

Please Help!

It is working fine when I click print button through the crystal report but when I close the report form back to my datagridview an error pop up about 
Conversion from type "DBNull" to type 'string' is not valid

Here is my code where I can retrieve data from my database to my datagridview

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfsesmis"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        adapter.Fill(dt)

        For Each row In dt.Rows
            Populate(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7), row(8), row(9), row(10), row(11))
        Next
        con.Close()

        dt.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: What runs when you close the window???

Comment: My search form where I search and click the print button. ! But after I can view or click the print button and close the report form! The search form will load up all the fields but if I click any button or the print button again, it shows the error

Comment: Where's your search form code and have you set breakpoints to step through?

Comment: btw I use CrystalReport in Reporting!

Comment: its too long to put it in here sir

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to check for [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx) values before sending these somewhere else :

```
If IsDBNull(row(x)) Then 
    value = "" 
Else 
    value = row(x)
End If
```

Also, you want to use [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) block for your connection, because here you only close it if there is an Exception (which means you really don't trust yourself...)

Here is an example (I don't know how you create your Connection) :

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfsesmis"

Try
    Using con As New SQLConnection()
        con.Open()   
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        adapter.Fill(dt)

        For Each row In dt.Rows
            'It's in your Populate function that you want to check the DBNull values
            Populate(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7), row(8), row(9), row(10), row(11))
        Next

        dt.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    End Using 'con Object will be disposed automatically
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: where will I put the IsDBNull? and what declarations may it be ? for value and row?